# Cannot test many-to-many references in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to test m2m reference that I've created. In models, it's like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} by {self.user.__str__()}'


@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

My test looks as follows:

```py
def test_create_list(self):
    self.create_user("test_user") # returns User.objects.create_user
    extended_user = Profile.objects.get(pk = 1)
    l = List.objects.create(
        name = "2019"
    )
    l.user.add(extended_user)
    self.assertEqual(l.__str__(), f"2019 by {extended_user.__str__()}")
```

This results in a failed test:

```
Expected :'2019 by hay.Profile.None'
Actual   :'2019 by test_user'
```

Why this `hay.Profile.None` comes up? I tried adding `l.save()` before the assertion, but it doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: since `user` is a `ManyToManyField`, this is not *one* `profile`, but a collection of `Profile`s.

Answer (score 2):

You have a many-to-many relation. That means, as the name implies, *many* items on each side. You can't just say `self.user`; that's an accessor to *many* users that are related to `self`. You need to query all those users, then do something to format them suitably for a string; for example, joining them with commas.

Note also, you should never call double-underscore methods directly. Use the built-in function, eg `str(whatever)`. So:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name} by {', '.join(str(user) for user in self.user.all())}'
```

and

```
self.assertEqual(str(l), f"2019 by {str(extended_user)}")
```

but in order to be a proper test, you should probably create *several* linked Profiles for a List.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But, I might have created the wrong relation here. I assued m2m because "many users" can have "many lists" (and those lists are users only, never shared). Is there other relation I should choose?

Comment: Well, if a user can have many lists and a list can have many users, then a many-to-many is what you want. If a list can only have one user but a user can have many lists, then you need a ForeignKey.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see if m2o suits this better ;) You've been a great help, thank you!